# visual studio watch: node not supported

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having problem with VS2013 watches. For example a watch that adds two floats is ok but adding a double and a float is not. Why is that and what should be done? 
This is a game project using Unity3d and the .Net version is 3.5.
[image]

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @JasonThuli No. Still have the problem:(

Comment: The issue is still there in Unity3D from our perspective, quite hard to do advanced debuging

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use VS studio 2015 since unity recommends that version integrated with the `vs studio tools for unity` where there is a lot of advanced debugging tools, just like rendering debug and everything is simplified for that version.

- Visual studio tools for unity - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx

There is a tutorial about how to install that tools and connect them:

https://youtu.be/lKHCrRNTf_s?list=PLReL099Y5nRfseAg0k1SJOlpqdcsDs8Em

https://youtu.be/vAcSTo6w2Ts